# Powershell Move-Item that is NOT in a list

Tags: powershell

I have a list of folders, these folders are the ones I want to keep. I'd like to move all other folders that are NOT in the list.

This will move the files in the list

```
$file_list = "Folder-A", "Folder-B", "Folder-C" 
$source_folder = "C:\Move-Folders-Test\Shop-Test"
$destination_folder = "C:\Move-Folders-Test\Archive-Test"

foreach ($file in $file_list) {
   Move-Item $source_folder\$file $destination_folder
}
```

How can I move the ones that are not in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) with the `Exclude` param will do what you want:

```
$file_list = "Folder-A", "Folder-B", "Folder-C" 
$source_folder = "C:\Move-Folders-Test\Shop-Test"
$destination_folder = "C:\Move-Folders-Test\Archive-Test"

Get-ChildItem $source_folder -Exclude $file_list -Directory | Move-Item -Destination $destination_folder -WhatIf
```

Comment: Thanks James C. Should have found that myself.